# Swift Variable Initialization via Type Instance

Tags: swift, variables, types, initialization, instance

I want to declare some variables at the beginning of a class and have their values be modified later and elsewhere. I'd rather not assign an initial garbage value to these to keep things concise.

Can I declare variables of basic types by declaring them as instances of the type? An example of what I mean is this:

```
class foo() {
    var isCool = Bool()
    var someInteger = Int()

    func gotTheFunc() -> Bool {
        isCool = true
        return isCool
    }
}
```

The compiler lets me do this, but is it something I actually can / should do when declaring class properties like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should set the properties in an init method, then you do not have to assign a value at declaration. For example:

```
init(someInt: Int, isCool: Bool) {
    self.isCool = isCool
    self.someInteger = someInt
}
```

The self keyword is not necessary, but makes it clear which is the class's property.

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but what if I don't want the properties to have initial values at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that but when you declare variables with basic type initializers

```
var isCool = Bool()
var someInteger = Int()
```

the complier does this

```
var isCool = false
var someInteger = 0
```

If you want to declare variables with no value, you have to use optionals

```
var isCool : Bool?
var someInteger : Int?
```

but I would avoid optionals as much as possible.

Side note: class names should begin always with a capital letter

```
class Foo {}
```

Comment: Oh, okay. So Swift does have default values for basic types.

As far as readability goes, it seems like that's a much nicer and more concise way to declare properties. Unless I need to initialize those variables with a certain value it's okay to just let the compiler do the initialization for you.